# Environment Variables not working in Production

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, vercel

I am new to `env` and I just looked into '[How to add custom env to React projects](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/). I followed the steps described and it worked in the development. But, when I tried to open the site in Vercel and see the console, it is returning `undefined`. 
Here is my `.env`:

```
REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE=abcdef
```

`App.js`:

```
useEffect(() => {
 abcd();
 console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE);
}, []);
```

`envTest.js`:

```
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE);

export default function abcd() {
  console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE);
}
```

All of these were ready to go in development but went down in production.

[image: Error-Undefined]

Any help is greatly appreciated ! 
Thanks!

Comment: try creating a new file .env.production and move your production variables into this file. and then try to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your environment variables directly inside Vercel for production (when building your project, it does not copy over your `.env` file for security reasons).

To do this:

1. Login to Vercel
2. Go to your project
3. Head over project settings
4. Go to environment variables
5. Add the ones you need

More info [here](https://vercel.com/docs/environment-variables)